# Convolution in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to calculate this convolution:

x[n] = δ[n+1] + δ[n] - δ[n-1]

h[n] = (1/2)^n * u[n] . u[n] is the step function.

Here's my code:

```
>> n=[-10:10];
>> x=zeros(1,length(n));
>> x(n==-1)=1;
>> x(n==0)=1;
>> x(n==1)=-1;
>> u=heaviside(n);
>> h=(1/2).^n * u;
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
```

How do you exactly type my h[n]? What if it's u[n-1] instead?

Comment: The last line should probably be `h=(1/2).^n .* u;`, note the extra dot. I guess you want element-wise multiplication, not matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>  n=[-10:10];
>> x=zeros(1,length(n));
>> x(n==-1)=1;
>> x(n==0)=1;
>> x(n==1)=-1;
>> u=heaviside(n);
>> h=(1/2).^n .* u; %Note the element wise operation .*
>> conv(x,h)
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you happen to know how do I make a u[n-1] step function?

Comment: @user2280704 `y = (n >= 1)` See it using `stem(n,y)`